# react error my social media app is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarn-v2

```
const authReducer = (state = { authData: null, loading: false, error: false, updateLoading: false },action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AUTH_START":
      return {...state, loading: true, error: false };
    case "AUTH_SUCCESS":
      localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify({...action?.data}));
      return {...state,  authData: action.data, loading: false, error: false };
    case "AUTH_FAIL":
      return {...state, loading: false, error: true };
    case "UPDATING_START":
      return {...state, updateLoading: true , error: false}
    case "UPDATING_SUCCESS":
      localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify({...action?.data}));
      return {...state, authData: action.data, updateLoading: false, error: false}  
    case "UPDATING_FAIL":
      return {...state, updateLoading: true, error: true}
    case "LOG_OUT":
      localStorage.clear();
      return {...state,  authData: null, loading: false, error: false, updateLoading: false }
    case "FOLLOW_USER":
      return {...state, authData: {...state.authData, user: {...state.authData.user, following: [...state.authData.user.following, action.data]} }}
    case "UNFOLLOW_USER":
      return {...state, authData: {...state.authData, user: {...state.authData.user, following: [...state.authData.user.following.filter((personId)=>personId!==action.data)]} }}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Getting this error:

> `./src/reducers/AuthReducer.js` 21:78 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:78) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

[image]

Comment: ./src/reducers/AuthReducer.js 21:78
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:78)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: please format your code correctly

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I feel weird about this ternary operator with the spread operator

```
JSON.stringify({...action?.data})
```

You can't deal with the spread as a condition

and even that, for the ternary operator, you have a syntax error there

I recommend you to check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Or maybe, it has been added by mistake
and you mean this

```
JSON.stringify({...action.data})
```